# Do trees drop furniture in all colors and varieties or only the types sold in the shop in ACNH?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I've been shaking my hardwood and cedar trees every day to get two pieces of furniture.   However all the furniture I get seems to be the same colors sold in the shop:

- I only get the pink "cute" furniture line from trees and from my shop.
- If I get duplicate furniture from trees, it is always exactly the same color that I got before.  I've seen this with:

  - Freezer (white)
  - Light switch (white)
  - Study poster (colorful)

I've shaken my trees for about 90 days now and not seen any new furniture colors compared to what I've bought in my shop.

The only way I seem to be able to get new colors is from Redd, from balloons (rarely), or from trading.

Can trees actually drop a variety of furniture colors?  I ask because some forums [like this one](https://www.belltreeforums.com/threads/obtaining-all-the-furniture-with-all-the-the-color-variations.543486/) seem to indicate that you should be able to get color variations from trees, but it doesn't seem to happen for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trees only drop furniture of the colors found in your shop.

I time traveled for another month and shook my trees every day.   I didn't get any new furniture.  I did get several more items that appear in my shop:

- Red imperial furniture (shelf and screen)
- Brown rattan furniture (waste bin and end table)
- White cute furniture (sofa and tea table)

I guess I can't say for sure that they would NEVER drop new furniture, but if they do, they do it so rarely that it is not a feasible way to get all the colors of furniture in a reasonable amount of time.

During this time I visited Redd a few times and got new furniture pretty much every time:

- Box corner sofa in two colors I didn't have before
- Rattan stool in light brown

I also popped a balloon and received a blue cute wall-mounted clock.

Balloons and Redd will give you furniture colors not sold in your shop but your shop and trees seem to be limited to the same color for series of items.